# Transforming a header to row value in SQL

Tags: sql-server

Is this possible, to transform the 1st table to the 2nd One (See below)? 
I want to transform the header into row value of its field.

I used Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Sample Table

[image]

thanks for your suggestions.

The first table is the one existing in the database.

The second one is what I want to get in my query result. There is only one table source.

I thinking of using the UNPIVOT function to do this. Any Idea?

Comment: I think you forget to place tables, can you please update the question

Comment: Read about pivote in mssql server

Answer (score 0):

Try `UNION ALL` as below. I have considered only those columns which you have shown.

```
SELECT Header1 AS NewHeader1 ,'Header1' AS NewHeader2 FROM TableName
UNION ALL
SELECT Header2 AS NewHeader1 ,'Header2' AS NewHeader2 FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can just use a `Union All`

```
SELECT
    Newheader1 = Header1,
    Newheader2 = 'Header1'
    FROM YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT
    Newheader1 = Header2,
    Newheader2 = 'Header2'
    FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use of *cross apply* instead of `UNION ALL`

```
select a.* from table t
cross apply (
    values (Header1, 'Header1'),
           (Header2, 'Header2')
)a(NewHeader1, NewHeader2)
order by 1
```